# Group results by column value and order by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have this table (not the actual, but it's an example):

```
ID| VAL |  LOG |     DATE
1    1     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
2    2     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
3    3     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
4    1     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
5    6     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
6    2     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
```

I need a query to get the values in a more organized way.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE date BETWEEN '$begin 00:00:00' and '$end 23:59:59'
ORDER BY id desc
```

This would return this:

```
ID| VAL |  LOG |     DATE
6    2     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
5    6     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
4    1     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
3    3     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
2    2     bla    xx/xx/xxxx    
1    1     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
```

I wanted to get them organized by the VAL column, and order by id desc, of course.
So it should output this:

```
ID| VAL |  LOG |     DATE
5    6     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
3    3     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
6    2     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
2    2     bla    xx/xx/xxxx    
4    1     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
1    1     bla    xx/xx/xxxx
```

As you can see the items on the VAL column are all together.

How can i return this?

I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE date BETWEEN '$begin 00:00:00' and '$end 23:59:59'
ORDER BY id desc
GROUP BY val
```

But it returned only one row for each VAL item.

What is the proper way of getting this result?

Comment: use a compound order by `order by val desc, id asc`  Grouping is used with aggregate functions (min, max count)

Comment: Where's the php code here?

Comment: Why are you adding a GROUP BY clause instead of changing ORDER BY to Val Desc, Id, Desc ?

Comment: I tried before and didn't work very well... Thanks, xQbert

Comment: nao foi nada. @PhiterFernandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE date BETWEEN '$begin 00:00:00' and '$end 23:59:59'
ORDER BY val desc, id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a time component for the date comparisons.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM logs l
WHERE date >= '$begin' and date < date_add('$end', interval 1 day)
ORDER BY val desc, id desc;
```

If add the 1 day in the application for `$end`, then the query is even simpler:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM logs l
WHERE date >= '$begin' and date < '$end'
ORDER BY val desc, id desc;
```

You do not mention what you are using at the application layer.  In general, it is better to use parameters rather than user-defined strings in SQL statements.

Comment: Yeah the $begin and the $end are only dd/mm/yyyy, I used 23:59:59 so it would also get results of the $end day.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes unless the `date` field is a `datetime` or `timestamp`, you should not need a time component. Also, $begin and $end should be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format... unless `date` is a string data type, in which case you have bigger problems.

Comment: Yep the user inputs in dd/mm/yyyy and then this does the trick:

`$data = date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($row['date']));`